# Webview cuts off long urls incorrectly

Tags: android, webview

In my case `WebView` has no issues wrapping sentences which have spaces in them, but issue occurs when long url is present.

I have added a screenshot below (blacked out some parts for privacy). If you look at the url part - that is the issue. The url here should be https://somethingsomething.care/business-policy. Word "business-" is chopped off and is not visible.

How can this be fixed?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set horizontal scroll to WebView.
And webpage should be responsive to fit in mobile width.

Comment: Good point, maybe its the webpages issue, not the webviews 

Comment: Yep, just confirmed that it was an issue with the website itself... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try to set wide viewport for fitting whole content inside

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); // also worth trying
```

besides that page should be responsive and be able to fit to mobile screens

Comment: Tried it. Didn't help :/